# How do I populate a textbox with some data in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a controller (MigrateAccountController) with its own view.  It asks for a username and password then does some checking.  If the user checks out, I do a `return RedirectToAction("Register", "Account", user);`.

I want to populate the username and email textboxes with the data contained in user (its a RegisterModel type).  I've tried every incarnation that I can think of for the "htmlAttributes".  One example is `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName), new { value = Model.UserName })`

Basically I want to use the same view for two things.  If the view is passed a model containing data, then use that data to fill in the textboxes.  If the view is not passed anything, then do nothing and leave the textboxes blank.  Is this possible or should I split the views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A RedirectToAction issues a server side redirect which indicates to the browser to issue a new request at the given location. So there is no passing the model between actions using RedirectToAction (the third parameter is for a RouteValueDictionary). Either save the model in TempData, then RedirectToAction and then read the model from TempData in that action. Or why not just return the View instead of redirecting.

Comment: Awesome, returning the view works great.  However, now when I get to the register page I immediately get validation errors.  Is there anyway to populate those textboxes without firing the validation errors until the user tries to POST the data?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing any code or knowing why you don't want fields validated.

Comment: I do want them validated but the problem is that I get the validations right away.  In my controller I am returning the view like you said.  It shows up how I want it to except for the validation errors.  What code do you need?  Its pretty much just the default Register.cshtml that comes when you start a new web app.